# Adding Quantity Option to A Store Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a RoR custom store I'm building, and I'm just trying to put some bells and whistles.  I have my product model, which product#index as the root of my store...  each product has an add to cart button.  When You click add to cart, a line_item is created with quantity (1).  That looks like this.

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
     <%= link_to "#{product.title}", :action => 'show', :id => product %>
     <%= link_to(image_tag("#{product.image_url}", :size => "200x200"), product) %>
     <%= truncate product.description, length: 180 %> <%= link_to "read more", product %>
     <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(:product_id=> product), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I want to add a quantity selection box.  In the code above I'm not using a form_for or simple_form_for.  In order to add a quantity to the line_item that gets created, I would have to use a form_for (right?) So I added

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@line_item) do |f| %>
       <%= f.select :quantity, [1, 2, 3] %> 
          <%= f.button :submit, 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(:product_id=> product), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

*Update*

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@line_item, url:line_items_path(product_id:product)) do |f| %>
```

eliminates the argument error...  my problem now is that the quantity doesn't update...  I know why, but not certain how to fix.

Here is the controller when the line_item is created as per the submit button:

```
  def create
    @cart = current_cart
      product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
      @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
  ...
  end
```

the add_product method is only adding one.  The method I've defined in my cart.rb is as follows.

```
 def add_product(product_id)
  current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
   if current_item
    current_item.quantity += 1
   else
    current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product_id)
  end
  current_item
 end
```

Should I just scrap the method and declare the quantity = to the form value?  I'm a little rusty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with following

```
<%= form_for(@line_item,url:line_items_path(product_id:product)) do |f| %>
       <%= f.select :quantity, options_for_select([1,2,3]) %> 
       <%= f.submit, 'Add to Cart', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 <% end %>
```

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html for more details on form helpers

Comment: I no longer get the argument error, but the quantity doesn't work.  It adds one quantity regardless.  I need to have (@)line_item defined in the products_controller.  Right now I have @line_item = LineItem.new  is that wrong?

Comment: if u have @line_item = LineItem.new then above form will submit to create action of line_items_controller.

Comment: almost there... just seems that now that the product_id isn't being passed...  why wouldn't (product_id.product.id) work?

Comment: what are you using..? above form, or yours button_to..?

Comment: I am using the above form.

Comment: then it should work..i u have added the form inside your @products loop, if not then product must be instance variable with some value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55549/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-peege151).

Answer (score 0):

Please write your path with form for word

```
<% simple_form_for @line_item, path: line_item_path(product_Id: Product.id, method: 'POST') do %>
  <%= f.select :quantity, [1, 2, 3] %> 
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Add to Cart', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```